# Template placeholder not defined in return type of member, still works fine?

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following snippet, I omitted the template param placeholder in the return type of Assignment operator (operator=). In both the cases where I have specified the template parameter or not, the code just runs fine, just wondering why?

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

class Ref
{
    int _ref_counter;

public:
    Ref() : _ref_counter(0)     {}
    void upRef() { _ref_counter++; }

    int downRef() { return --_ref_counter; }
};

template <typename T1> class SmartPointer
{
    T1* _ptr;
    Ref *_ref;

public:
    SmartPointer() : _ptr(0)
    {
        _ref = new Ref();
        _ref->upRef();
    }

    SmartPointer(T1* ptr): _ptr(ptr)
    {
        _ref = new Ref();
        _ref->upRef();
    }

    SmartPointer(const SmartPointer &sp): _ptr(sp._ptr), _ref(sp._ref)
    {
    {
        _ref->upRef();
    }

//      SmartPointer<T1>& operator= (const SmartPointer &sp)
    SmartPointer& operator= (const SmartPointer &sp)
    {
        //Always check self assignment
        if(this != &sp)
        {
            //Lose the existing smartpointer info
            if(0 == _ref->downRef())
            {
                delete _ptr;
                delete _ref;
            }

            _ptr = sp._ptr;
            _ref = sp._ref;
            _ref->upRef();
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~SmartPointer()
    {
        if(0 == _ref->downRef())
        {
            delete _ptr;
            delete _ref;
        }
    }

    T1& operator* () { return *_ptr; }

    T1* operator-> () { return _ptr; }
};

class Lock
{
public:
    void somefuntion()
    {
        cout << "somefunction called ! " << endl;
    }

    ~Lock()
    {
        cout << "Destructor Lock called !" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    SmartPointer<Lock> pMemLock(new Lock());

    pMemLock->somefuntion();
    {
        SmartPointer<Lock> pMemLock1(pMemLock);
    }

    SmartPointer<Lock> pMemLock2;
    pMemLock2 = pMemLock;
    pMemLock2->somefuntion();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the standard [n3690: 14.6.1/1]:

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an
>   injected-class-name (Clause 9). The injected class-name can be used as
>   a template-name or a type-name. When it is used with a
>   template-argument-list, as a template-argument for a template
>   template-parameter, or as the final identifier in the elaborated-type
>   specifier of a friend class template declaration, it refers to the
>   class template itself. Otherwise, it is equivalent to the
>   template-name followed by the template-parameters of the class
>   template enclosed in <>.

Comment: It's always a good idea to add the section nr. (14.6.1/1 in your case) and standard version when quoting from the standard.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as injected class name. In a template `X<T>`, the name `X` is equivalent to `X<T>`. Here's an interesting example:

```
template<template<class T> class X>
class Y
{
};

template<class T>
class X;
{
    Y<X> mem; //won't compile, because X is not a template, but is equivalent to X<T>, which is a type.
};
```

See also: [Ambiguous injected class name is not an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025054/ambiguous-injected-class-name-is-not-an-error)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you refer to the template `X` from within `X`? I assume there must be some way. Presumably `::X` would work assuming that `X` is in the global namespace, but I hope there is a less ugly way.

Comment: @cdhowie: You'd write `Y< ::X>` :)

Comment: So there is no alternative to spelling out the complete name of the type, including namespaces?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan lol, when will we get rid of trigraphs so we can stop putting that space in there?

Comment: @Barry Isn't that because of the `<:` *digraph*, not a trigraph?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't build? @LauraM's answer quoting C++11 14.6.1/1 seems to indicate it should, and [gcc agrees](http://ideone.com/J0riXg).

Comment: @cdhowie - oh yeah. Same idea though.

Comment: @cdhowie There's a special rule for the `<::` case that makes it work. [lex.pptoken]/p3, 2nd bullet point. Also, `Y<X>` should work in the example; if it doesn't it's a compiler bug.